# Anyone running Zend server 7 on openshift?

Tags: zend-framework, openshift

It doesn't appear to be one of their pre-packaged installers. Although I've searched, i cannot find an answer as to whether Zend server 7 is supported by openshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Zend Server 7 is not available on OpenShift, however you can use zend-6.1.  You might try checking the public Trello boards to see if Zend Server 7 is in the works: https://trello.com/openshift